# issue with floated divs in IE7 and IE6

Tags: css

I have floated two elements right in the header of my website which are `<div id="twitter">` and `<div id ="navbar>`, but there appearance becomes skewed when I view them in IE6 and IE7. I believe that I either need to clear the floated elements or apply a clearfix but I am unsure as to where.

here is an image of the issue in IE6 and IE7:

[image]

This is the desired result as it would appear in modern browsers.

[image]

Here is a link to the web page: http://www.bestcastleintown.co.uk/pg/

CSS:

```
#twitter {
    background: red;
    float: right;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 200px;
}

#navbar {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    float:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main_header">
    <div id="inner_main_header">
        <div>
            <div id="main_logo">
                <div class="home_page_logo left">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="PG_awards_logo.gif"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id ="twitter" class="padall">
                    Follow us
                </div>
                <div id ="navbar" class="right">
                    <ul class="nav NG">
                        <li>home</li>
                        <li>enter</li>
                        <li>categories</li>
                        <li>judging</li>
                        <li>sponsorship</li>
                        <li>contact</li>
                    </ul>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the html and css here? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: If you are making changes to the code after posting a question here, please stop. Make a static copy of the code as it is now, that will not change, and reference that.

Comment: I will do this now - the current location is a static copy of the code that will not be changed.

Comment: You need to support IE6? I feel bad for you, son. I got 99 problems but Trident ain't one.

Comment: Not me, my manager - the traffic to our site still receives 1% IE6 users so therefore we must make the site work for these older browsers. He is the reason I'm leaving my job next month.

Comment: @user1554264 What is the desired result? It's unclear to me

Comment: @Evan desired result screenshot attached - desired result should also show in latest chrome/ie/firefox. There is a link in the post.

Comment: FYI - the image attached is not how it looks for me in Chrome. I may have a smaller window size than you though

Answer (score 0):

Change `#navbar` style to this:

```
#navbar{
    font-size: 2.2em;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Just give the `#navbar` some width and overflow other than visible.